# Ideas for sealing kitchen sink pvc pipe to bottom of strainer that sheared off (old)

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, drain, sink

Sink from at least the 60s, probably the late 30's. New kitchen relocation maybe in a year, but pipe seal burst at drain and when reattached new pvc nut it sheared off most of the bottom of strainer. Strainer nut is original corroded metal and will not budge. All night soak in vinegar removed the corrosion, but strainer will still not budge with any tool. There is enough thread to hold on the pvc nut, but gasket can be pulled from the top and water runs through the gap between strainer and pipe.
Not worried about aesthetics just can't afford a plumber or replacement tools to do it right (and I would probably puncture the sink anyway). I checked Habitat for a replacement over mount sink, but didn't have any yesterday. 
Plumber's putty apparently won't work and maybe JB weld is worth a try, but the connection would be pvc to copper. I could close the sink, but it has a dishwasher and I believe that it needs to back wash into it, so water would come from the other direction. With a family it would be nice to still have 2 sinks though.
Looking for affordable ideas/suggestions for this jury-rig. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Adding a picture would really help here; it's hard to understand what you're talking about.

Comment: I agree. Some photos are really necessary here...You said that the whole bottom of the strainer sheered off and yet you say that the strainer nut will not budge....This leaves enough confusion space that there is not good basis against which to attempt an answer.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using a drill bit and chisel to break the solid ring to replace the strainer. The men at Home Depot kept insisting I was incorrect that it was light metal. It was very thick and strong placed many decades ago. I was disappointed they refused to offer me other options. Oh well..